# App to log your time or day?

Tags: logging, time-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring my own activity on computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer)

What app can i use to log what i am doing each hour? I prefer something to come up on screen at every interval.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer

Comment: also: http://superuser.com/questions/917/time-tracking-applications and http://superuser.com/questions/53235/task-and-time-management-tracking-software-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) and [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/). Both monitor the applications you are using, and allow you to associate it with an activity later. The difference is the former stores data locally only, while the latter sends data to their website, and allows you to see aggregates.

Also, check out the comments on [Lifehacker Hive Five](http://lifehacker.com/5361289/best-time+tracking-application) and the [results](http://lifehacker.com/5361289/best-time+tracking-application).

Answer (score 0):

I love [AllNetic working time tracker](http://www.allnetic.com/). It allows fine-grained management of projects, detects when you're away from the computer, and can export data to XML.